# Remove/Change Android password

Tags: security, password, password-protection

A friend gave me an old Android tablet (**Medion Junior Tab S7322**) which dates back into the Android 4.4 days and asked if I can get access to his pictures on the internal storage because she forgot her password she had set up a bunch of years ago.

I started researching how something like that can be done and now I ended up here, asking if someone knows any method to "**break-in**" or recover data from the internal memory since all other methods/attempts were either not viable or have failed, due to Androids security restrictions.

There is no linked Google account, no pattern lock, and debug mode is off.
Though I assume this device has a JTAG connector on the mainboard, which I couldn't verify yet, since I don't want to open the device till all other methods have been exhausted.

1. Are there any tools that can remove/change the password on a tablet via USB connection, ignoring all of the security locks by exploiting known vulnerabilities on the tablet model/ Android 4.4?
2. Can you maybe brute-force the password, since my friend mentioned it probably wasn't too secure.

Comment: you can use [rkDumper](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/2915363) or similar

Comment: device is not encrypted, plain dump of mtd partition is sufficient, can be read offline on linux PC. no need to bruteforce, just delete locksettings.db

Comment: How do you access the partition when the device is preventing you to connect to it? Don't you have to enable file transfer first (as you might see, I am a noob with Android devices ;)

Comment: I have no recovery tools such as TWRP (i believe it's called) / others installed on the tablet. Debug mode is also off, so I assume ADB won't work either?

Comment: RockChip devices come with [rockusb](https://roc-rk3328-cc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flash_emmc.html) mode. from what I have read rkDumper should work in [fastboot](https://opensource.rock-chips.com/wiki_Fastboot) mode. read [here](https://winstonhyypia.medium.com/how-to-backup-and-restore-android-system-on-rockchip-device-c7058098216) about drivers. you can also ask in [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/2915363) thread. you want userdata partition

Comment: this is example how it looks like https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-rkdumper-utility-for-backup-firmware-of-rockchips-devices.2915363/post-82857089

Comment: once you have dump, it should be possible to port [CWM clockworkmod recovery](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610105229/http://androtab.info/clockworkmod/rockchip) for this device (from RK30GENERIC_CWM.zip) then you can boot [Aroma file manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1646108) and delete `locksettings.db` from CWM recovery